# Email server issue in Joomla

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, joomla

For the past 2 weeks I am getting problem with my website Contact Us form. My website is built in Joomla. Whenever I filled the form for testing, I got the mail to my Gmail account but not on my domain email ID's.

My joomla website is hosted on AWS and the email server is a dedicated server. My website is running pretty good.

My mail settings in joomla admin are:

- Send mail: yes
- Mailer: sendmail
- Sendmail path: /usr/sbin/sendmail

What is wrong with my Contact Us form?

Comment: Sad to hear you have problems with your contact us form. But without any error message I doubt that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: This question is too generic, but if it's worth anything, AWS blocks mail services by default: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=227924

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is (we experienced the same issue before with one of our clients). Your website's domain has an SPF entry that doesn't include the IP of your server. This means that when someone tries to fill in a "Contact Us" form and then send it, then it will possibly get caught by your domain's spam filter since the IP of your server is not allowed to send emails on behalf of your domain.

The solution to this problem is to add an SPF entry for your server's IP in your domain's DNS settings.